# How to View XML Preview Without Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I Want to Know is there any Process to preview the "**Drawable XML**" file Just like in Android Studio Without Using the Studio.

I searched the Internet but i didn't Find any relevant data.

I wanted To see the Design/Preview Not the code in Tree View or in Beautify Mode .
whenever i want to edit the xml file , i have to use the android studio to preview it or already developed file,it seems a bit difficult to do so,is there any easy process to preview the xml file.

Answer (score 4):

You Can Use **udacity visualizer**

But Not All Features Available  Like Gravity  Or layoutDirection

https://labs.udacity.com/android-visualizer/

Comment: Thanx man ,atleast it is something